# Core dump when trying to start greenfoot

Tags: java, linux, jvm, greenfoot

I am trying to start greenfoot on my machine with out much success.
The OS is arch linux. 
I downloaded the *Greenfoot-generic-310.jar* and installed it with

```
java -jar Greenfoot-generic-310.jar
```

Java *open-jdk-8* and  *java-openjfx-8.u172-1* are installed along bluej 4.1.2.1

Whenever i try to start greenfoot i get this error message:

```
$ ./greenfoot                                                                                                                 
A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:   
SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f653efe73b8, pid=11568, tid=0x00007f653d4cb700
JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (8.0_162-b12) (build 1.8.0_162-b12)
Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.162-b12 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
Problematic frame:
V  [libjvm.so+0x6b73b8]

Core dump written. Default location: /home/name/builds/greenfoot/core or core.11568

An error report file with more information is saved as:
/home/name/builds/greenfoot/hs_err_pid11568.log

If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp

./greenfoot: line 5: 11568 Aborted                 (core dumped) "$JAVAPATH/bin/java" -cp "$CP" bluej.Boot -greenfoot=true -bluej.compiler.showunchecked=false "$@"
```

Thankful for any suggestions that may solve this.

EDIT1: Adding the content of the file hs_err_pid11568.log. The file has been pruned to fit in this question. I hope i did not delete important information.

```
---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x00007f649804b000 JavaThread "vm-event-handler" [_thread_blocked, id=11628, stack(0x00007f64b512d000,0x00007f64b522e000)]
  0x00007f6498047800 JavaThread "BlueJ I/O Handler" [_thread_blocked, id=11627, stack(0x00007f64b522e000,0x00007f64b532f000)]
  0x00007f6498046800 JavaThread "BlueJ I/O Handler" [_thread_in_native, id=11626, stack(0x00007f64b532f000,0x00007f64b5430000)]
  0x00007f6498045000 JavaThread "BlueJ I/O Handler" [_thread_in_native, id=11625, stack(0x00007f64b5430000,0x00007f64b5531000)]
  0x00007f64c45a6800 JavaThread "Image Fetcher 1" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=11624, stack(0x00007f64b5731000,0x00007f64b5832000)]
  0x00007f649803e800 JavaThread "JDI Target VM Interface" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=11623, stack(0x00007f64b5832000,0x00007f64b5933000)]
  0x00007f649803b800 JavaThread "JDI Internal Event Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=11622, stack(0x00007f64b5933000,0x00007f64b5a34000)]
  0x00007f64d0154800 JavaThread "Prism Font Disposer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=11618, stack(0x00007f64b5a4f000,0x00007f64b5b50000)]
  0x000055e7be69d800 JavaThread "pool-3-thread-4" [_thread_blocked, id=11617, stack(0x00007f64b5e09000,0x00007f64b5f0a000)]
  0x000055e7be69c000 JavaThread "pool-3-thread-3" [_thread_blocked, id=11616, stack(0x00007f64b5f0a000,0x00007f64b600b000)]
  0x000055e7be69a000 JavaThread "pool-3-thread-2" [_thread_blocked, id=11615, stack(0x00007f64b600b000,0x00007f64b610c000)]
  0x000055e7be699000 JavaThread "pool-3-thread-1" [_thread_in_native, id=11614, stack(0x00007f64b610c000,0x00007f64b620d000)]
  0x00007f649801d800 JavaThread "process reaper" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=11605, stack(0x00007f64b640d000,0x00007f64b6446000)]
  0x00007f64c456e000 JavaThread "Thread-10" [_thread_blocked, id=11602, stack(0x00007f64b6446000,0x00007f64b6547000)]
  0x00007f64c4565800 JavaThread "Thread-9" [_thread_blocked, id=11601, stack(0x00007f64b6fb5000,0x00007f64b70b6000)]
  0x00007f64c4373800 JavaThread "GC Daemon" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=11599, stack(0x00007f64b72b6000,0x00007f64b73b7000)]
  0x00007f64c435b000 JavaThread "RMI Reaper" [_thread_blocked, id=11598, stack(0x00007f64b73b7000,0x00007f64b74b8000)]

  0x00007f64d40b5000 JavaThread "AWT-EventQueue-0" [_thread_blocked, id=11591, stack(0x00007f64dcd8a000,0x00007f64dce8b000)]
  0x00007f64d40b3800 JavaThread "AWT-Shutdown" [_thread_blocked, id=11590, stack(0x00007f64dce8b000,0x00007f64dcf8c000)]
  0x00007f64d40af000 JavaThread "AWT-XAWT" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=11589, stack(0x00007f64dd18c000,0x00007f64dd28d000)]
  0x00007f64d409e000 JavaThread "Java2D Disposer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=11588, stack(0x00007f64dd28d000,0x00007f64dd38e000)]
  0x00007f64d003d000 JavaThread "Thread-3" [_thread_blocked, id=11587, stack(0x00007f64ddb1d000,0x00007f64ddc1e000)]
  0x00007f64e415c000 JavaThread "JavaFX Application Thread" [_thread_in_native, id=11586, stack(0x00007f64ddc1e000,0x00007f64ddd1f000)]
  0x00007f64e4159000 JavaThread "Thread-2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=11585, stack(0x00007f64ddd1f000,0x00007f64dde20000)]
  0x00007f64e4059000 JavaThread "QuantumRenderer-0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=11584, stack(0x00007f6521b02000,0x00007f6521c03000)]
  0x00007f65381bf800 JavaThread "JavaFX-Launcher" [_thread_blocked, id=11583, stack(0x00007f6521c03000,0x00007f6521d04000)]
  0x00007f65380c7800 JavaThread "Service Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=11581, stack(0x00007f6521e9b000,0x00007f6521f9c000)]
  0x00007f65380bc800 JavaThread "C1 CompilerThread2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=11580, stack(0x00007f6521f9d000,0x00007f652209d000)]
  0x00007f65380ba800 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=11579, stack(0x00007f652209e000,0x00007f652219e000)]
  0x00007f65380b8000 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=11578, stack(0x00007f652219f000,0x00007f652229f000)]
  0x00007f65380b6800 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=11577, stack(0x00007f652229f000,0x00007f65223a0000)]
  0x00007f6538083800 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=11576, stack(0x00007f65281f2000,0x00007f65282f3000)]
  0x00007f653807f000 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=11575, stack(0x00007f65282f3000,0x00007f65283f4000)]
  0x00007f653800a000 JavaThread "main" [_thread_blocked, id=11569, stack(0x00007f65405a5000,0x00007f65406a5000)]



=>0x00007f653801f000 (exited) GCTaskThread [stack: 0x00007f653d3cc000,0x00007f653d4cc000] [id=11570]

VM state:at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread:  ([mutex/lock_event])
[0x00007f65380076e0] Threads_lock - owner thread: 0x00007f6538077800
[0x00007f6538007be0] Heap_lock - owner thread: 0x000055e7be69c000


CodeCache: size=245760Kb used=5820Kb max_used=5833Kb free=239939Kb
 bounds [0x00007f6529000000, 0x00007f65295c0000, 0x00007f6538000000]
 total_blobs=2596 nmethods=1754 adapters=756
 compilation: enabled

Compilation events (10 events):
Event: 2.296 Thread 0x00007f65380bc800 1778       1       sun.awt.image.ImageWatched$AccWeakReference::access$000 (5 bytes)
Event: 2.297 Thread 0x00007f65380bc800 nmethod 1778 0x00007f65295b3390 code [0x00007f65295b34e0, 0x00007f65295b35d0]
Event: 2.298 Thread 0x00007f65380b8000 nmethod 1717 0x00007f65295af590 code [0x00007f65295af740, 0x00007f65295afd00]
Event: 2.298 Thread 0x00007f65380b8000 1721       4       javassist.bytecode.ExceptionTable::<init> (91 bytes)
Event: 2.299 Thread 0x00007f65380bc800 1780       1       javax.swing.AbstractButton::getText (5 bytes)
Event: 2.299 Thread 0x00007f65380bc800 nmethod 1780 0x00007f65295af2d0 code [0x00007f65295af420, 0x00007f65295af530]
Event: 2.306 Thread 0x00007f65380bc800 1781       2       java.util.Calendar::internalSet (8 bytes)
Event: 2.306 Thread 0x00007f65380bc800 nmethod 1781 0x00007f65295aef10 code [0x00007f65295af080, 0x00007f65295af1f0]
Event: 2.311 Thread 0x00007f65380b8000 nmethod 1721 0x00007f65295adfd0 code [0x00007f65295ae1a0, 0x00007f65295ae920]
Event: 2.311 Thread 0x00007f65380b8000 1779       4       javassist.bytecode.FieldInfo::read (70 bytes)



Internal exceptions (10 events):
Event: 0.898 Thread 0x00007f64d003d000 Exception <a 'java/lang/ClassNotFoundException': RootPane> (0x00000000ed35dcc0) thrown at [/build/java8-openjdk/src/jdk8u-jdk8u162-b12/hotspot/src/share/vm/classfile/systemDictionary.cpp, line 210]
Event: 1.079 Thread 0x00007f64d40b5000 Implicit null exception at 0x00007f65292a0db5 to 0x00007f65292a1165
Event: 1.080 Thread 0x00007f64d40b5000 Implicit null exception at 0x00007f6529267df6 to 0x00007f65292681a9
Event: 1.212 Thread 0x00007f64d40b5000 Exception <a 'java/io/FileNotFoundException'> (0x00000000ed7c13d8) thrown at [/build/java8-openjdk/src/jdk8u-jdk8u162-b12/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jni.cpp, line 709]
Event: 1.387 Thread 0x00007f64d40b5000 Exception <a 'java/lang/NullPointerException'> (0x00000000ed7c7038) thrown at [/build/java8-openjdk/src/jdk8u-jdk8u162-b12/hotspot/src/share/vm/interpreter/linkResolver.cpp, line 1185]
Event: 1.387 Thread 0x00007f64d40b5000 Exception <a 'java/lang/NullPointerException'> (0x00000000ed7c7038) thrown at [/build/java8-openjdk/src/jdk8u-jdk8u162-b12/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jvm.cpp, line 1394]
Event: 1.417 Thread 0x00007f64d40b5000 Exception <a 'java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError': org/apache/xerces/impl/Version> (0x00000000ed97cc50) thrown at [/build/java8-openjdk/src/jdk8u-jdk8u162-b12/hotspot/src/share/vm/classfile/systemDictionary.cpp, line 199]
Event: 1.417 Thread 0x00007f64d40b5000 Exception <a 'java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError': org/apache/xerces/parsers/SAXParser> (0x00000000ed98a028) thrown at [/build/java8-openjdk/src/jdk8u-jdk8u162-b12/hotspot/src/share/vm/classfile/systemDictionary.cpp, line 199]
Event: 1.417 Thread 0x00007f64d40b5000 Exception <a 'java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError'> (0x00000000ed98a028) thrown at [/build/java8-openjdk/src/jdk8u-jdk8u162-b12/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jvm.cpp, line 1394]
Event: 1.440 Thread 0x00007f64d40b5000 Exception <a 'java/io/FileNotFoundException'> (0x00000000eda04e40) thrown at [/build/java8-openjdk/src/jdk8u-jdk8u162-b12/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jni.cpp, line 709]

Events (10 events):
Event: 2.309 loading class com/sun/tools/jdi/EventRequestManagerImpl$ThreadDeathRequestImpl
Event: 2.309 loading class com/sun/tools/jdi/EventRequestManagerImpl$ThreadDeathRequestImpl done
Event: 2.310 loading class bluej/debugger/jdi/VMEventHandler
Event: 2.310 loading class bluej/debugger/jdi/VMEventHandler done
Event: 2.313 Thread 0x000055e7be69a000 DEOPT PACKING pc=0x00007f65294554fb sp=0x00007f64b610a460
Event: 2.313 Thread 0x000055e7be69a000 DEOPT UNPACKING pc=0x00007f65290474c4 sp=0x00007f64b610a1b8 mode 0
Event: 2.314 Thread 0x000055e7be69a000 DEOPT PACKING pc=0x00007f6529543540 sp=0x00007f64b610a320
Event: 2.314 Thread 0x000055e7be69a000 DEOPT UNPACKING pc=0x00007f65290474c4 sp=0x00007f64b610a0d0 mode 0
Event: 2.316 Thread 0x00007f649804b000 Thread added: 0x00007f649804b000
Event: 2.316 Executing VM operation: ParallelGCFailedAllocation


Dynamic libraries:

55e7bd358000-55e7bd359000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 568500                     /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk/jre/bin/java
55e7bd558000-55e7bd559000 r--p 00000000 08:05 568500                     /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk/jre/bin/java
55e7bd559000-55e7bd55a000 rw-p 00001000 08:05 568500                     /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk/jre/bin/java
55e7be644000-55e7be6a7000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [heap]

7f64b5a34000-7f64b5a4f000 r--s 001d6000 08:05 568592                     /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar
7f64b5a4f000-7f64b5a52000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f64b5a52000-7f64b5b50000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f64b5b50000-7f64b5c09000 r--p 00000000 08:05 927043                     /usr/share/fonts/TTF/DejaVuSans.ttf

7f64b6747000-7f64b6764000 r--p 00000000 00:28 414381                     /tmp/+JXF4516869794534642796.tmp
7f64b6764000-7f64b6789000 r--p 00000000 00:28 414378                     /tmp/+JXF282881848008397155.tmp
7f64b6789000-7f64b67a6000 r--p 00000000 00:28 414375                     /tmp/+JXF108919475850951753.tmp
7f64b67a6000-7f64b67aa000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 546385                     /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk/jre/lib/amd64/libjavafx_font_pango.so
7f64b6bb0000-7f64b6bb1000 rw-p 00005000 08:05 546384                     /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk/jre/lib/amd64/libjavafx_font_freetype.so

7f64b7bbb000-7f64b7bc0000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 393938                     /usr/lib/libnss_dns-2.26.so


7f64dc009000-7f64dc00a000 r--s 00010000 08:05 568595                     /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar
7f64dc00a000-7f64dc02f000 r--p 00000000 00:28 414372                     /tmp/+JXF5283809112223520806.tmp
7f64dc02f000-7f64dc04b000 r--s 00393000 08:05 568596                     /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar
7f64dc04b000-7f64dc055000 r--s 00116000 08:05 568598                     /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar
7f64dc055000-7f64dc057000 r--s 00005000 08:06 6293776                    /home/name/builds/greenfoot/lib/httpmime-4.1.1.jar
7f64dc057000-7f64dc05c000 r--s 00028000 08:06 6293775                    /home/name/builds/greenfoot/lib/httpcore-4.1.jar
7f64dc05c000-7f64dc065000 r--s 0005d000 08:06 6293122                    /home/name/builds/greenfoot/lib/commons-vfs2-2.0.jar
7f64dc065000-7f64dc090000 r--s 001f9000 08:06 6293772                    /home/name/builds/greenfoot/lib/guava-17.0.jar
....
7f64dd290000-7f64dd38e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f64dd38e000-7f64dd3f0000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 568563                     /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk/jre/lib/amd64/libfontmanager.so
7f64dd3f0000-7f64dd5f0000 ---p 00062000 08:05 568563                     /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk/jre/lib/amd64/libfontmanager.so

7f64dd848000-7f64dd84b000 rw-p 00054000 08:05 568556                     /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk/jre/lib/amd64/libawt_xawt.so
7f64dd84b000-7f64dd84c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f64dd84c000-7f64dd8ed000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 568568                     /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk/jre/lib/amd64/libawt.so 
....  
7f6518000000-7f6518008000 r--s 0004e000 08:06 6293774                    /home/name/builds/greenfoot/lib/httpclient-4.1.1.jar
7f6518008000-7f6518012000 r--s 000a3000 08:06 6293883                    /home/name/builds/greenfoot/lib/javassist-3.18.0.jar
7f6518012000-7f651801a000 r--s 00045000 08:06 6294828                    /home/name/builds/greenfoot/lib/xom-1.2.9.jar
7f651801a000-7f651801c000 r--s 00021000 08:06 6293884                    /home/name/builds/greenfoot/lib/jl1.0.1.jar
7f651801c000-7f651801e000 r--s 0000a000 08:06 6293119                    /home/name/builds/greenfoot/lib/commons-codec-1.3.jar
7f651801e000-7f6518024000 r--s 00045000 08:06 6293120                    /home/name/builds/greenfoot/lib/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar
7f6518024000-7f6518026000 r--s 00006000 08:06 6293157                    /home/name/builds/greenfoot/lib/diffutils-1.2.1.jar
7f6518026000-7f651802f000 r--s 00069000 08:06 6293213                    /home/name/builds/greenfoot/lib/extensions/submitter.jar
7f651802f000-7f651803d000 r--s 00000000 08:05 132060                     /var/cache/fontconfig/491f45a0a771fef1c10b9b647a97fb82-le64.cache-7
7f651803d000-7f6518050000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 393923                     /usr/lib/libresolv-2.26.so
7f6518050000-7f6518250000 ---p 00013000 08:05 393923                     /usr/lib/libresolv-2.26.so
7f6518250000-7f6518251000 r--p 00013000 08:05 393923                     /usr/lib/libresolv-2.26.so
7f6518251000-7f6518252000 rw-p 00014000 08:05 393923                     /usr/lib/libresolv-2.26.so
7f6518252000-7f6518254000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f6518254000-7f6518260000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 415328                     /usr/lib/libxcb-render.so.0.0.0
....
7f651c021000-7f6520000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f6520000000-7f6520001000 r--s 00000000 08:06 6293905                    /home/name/builds/greenfoot/lib/lang-stride.jar
7f6520001000-7f6520007000 r--s 00036000 08:06 6293888                    /home/name/builds/greenfoot/lib/junit-4.11.jar
7f6520007000-7f6520013000 r--s 00000000 08:05 132429                     /var/cache/fontconfig/f6b893a7224233d96cb72fd88691c0b4-le64.cache-7
7f6520013000-7f6520031000 r--s 00259000 08:06 6293034                    /home/name/builds/greenfoot/lib/bluejcore.jar
7f6520031000-7f652003e000 r--s 00190000 08:06 6293212                    /home/name/builds/greenfoot/lib/extensions/greenfoot.jar
7f652003e000-7f6520051000 r--s 00346000 08:05 568526                     /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk/jre/lib/resources.jar
7f6520051000-7f65200cb000 r--s 010ff000 08:05 568641                     /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk/lib/tools.jar
7f65200cb000-7f65200de000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 426776                     /usr/lib/libpangoft2-1.0.so.0.4000.13
7f65200de000-7f65202dd000 ---p 00013000 08:05 426776                     /usr/lib/libpangoft2-1.0.so.0.4000.13
7f65202dd000-7f65202de000 r--p 00012000 08:05 426776                     /usr/lib/libpangoft2-1.0.so.0.4000.13

7f6520688000-7f6520689000 rw-p 001a9000 08:05 405627                     /usr/lib/libgio-2.0.so.0.5400.3
7f6520689000-7f652068b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f652068b000-7f65206ae000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 403871                     /usr/lib/libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0.3600.10
7f65206ae000-7f65208ad000 ---p 00023000 08:05 403871                     /usr/lib/libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0.3600.10
7f65208ad000-7f65208ae000 r--p 00022000 08:05 403871                     /usr/lib/libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0.3600.10
7f65208ae000-7f65208af000 rw-p 00023000 08:05 403871                     /usr/lib/libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0.3600.10
7f65208af000-7f65209cc000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 419444                     /usr/lib/libcairo.so.2.11510.0

7f6524021000-7f6528000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f6528000000-7f6528002000 r--s 00009000 08:06 6293773                    /home/name/builds/greenfoot/lib/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar
7f6528002000-7f6528004000 r--s 00000000 08:05 159961                     /var/cache/fontconfig/6ba42ae0000f58711b5caaf10d690066-le64.cache-7

7f652801f000-7f6528023000 rw-s 00000000 00:2a 415685                     /i915 (deleted)
7f6528023000-7f6528049000 r--p 00000000 08:05 432193                     /usr/share/locale/en_GB/LC_MESSAGES/gtk20-properties.mo
7f6528049000-7f6528057000 r--p 00000000 08:05 432194                     /usr/share/locale/en_GB/LC_MESSAGES/gtk20.mo
7f6528057000-7f65281f2000 r--p 00000000 08:05 444636                     /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive


7f653c000000-7f653c001000 r--s 00003000 08:06 6293908                    /home/name/builds/greenfoot/lib/opencsv-2.3.jar
7f653c001000-7f653c003000 r--s 00004000 08:06 6292253                    /home/name/builds/greenfoot/lib/AppleJavaExtensions.jar
7f653c003000-7f653c008000 rw-s 00000000 00:2a 415684                     /i915 (deleted)
7f653c008000-7f653c4bd000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f653c4bd000-7f653c68c000 r--s 03c2b000 08:05 568533                     /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk/jre/lib/rt.jar

7f653db82000-7f653db8a000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 568571                     /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk/jre/lib/amd64/libzip.so 
7f653dd8b000-7f653dd96000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 393937                     /usr/lib/libnss_files-2.26.so
7f653dd96000-7f653df95000 ---p 0000b000 08:05 393937                     /usr/lib/libnss_files-2.26.so
7f653df95000-7f653df96000 r--p 0000a000 08:05 393937                     /usr/lib/libnss_files-2.26.so
7f653df96000-7f653df97000 rw-p 0000b000 08:05 393937                     /usr/lib/libnss_files-2.26.so 
7f653f8b4000-7f653fa62000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 394008                     /usr/lib/libc-2.26.so  
7f653fe6e000-7f653fe6f000 rw-p 00003000 08:05 393931                     /usr/lib/libdl-2.26.so
7f653fe6f000-7f653fe7d000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 568575                     /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk/jre/lib/amd64/jli/libjli.so 
7f654007e000-7f6540094000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 402647                     /usr/lib/libz.so.1.2.11 
7f6540295000-7f65402ae000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 394030                     /usr/lib/libpthread-2.26.so 
7f65404af000-7f65404b3000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f65404b3000-7f65404d8000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 394009                     /usr/lib/ld-2.26.so
7f65404d8000-7f65404da000 r--s 00011000 08:06 6293088                    /home/name/builds/greenfoot/lib/bluejext.jar
7f65404da000-7f65404df000 rw-s 00000000 00:2a 412654                     /i915 (deleted)
7f65404df000-7f65405a4000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f65405a4000-7f65405a5000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f65405a5000-7f65405a8000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f65405a8000-7f65406a9000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f65406a9000-7f65406aa000 r--s 0000c000 08:06 6293121                    /home/name/builds/greenfoot/lib/commons-logging-api-1.1.2.jar
7f65406aa000-7f65406ab000 rw-s 00000000 00:05 415689                     /memfd:xshmfence (deleted)
7f65406ab000-7f65406ac000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7f65406ac000-7f65406b0000 rw-s 00000000 00:2a 416201                     /i915 (deleted)
7f65406b0000-7f65406b4000 rw-s 00000000 00:2a 416199                     /i915 (deleted)
7f65406b4000-7f65406b9000 rw-s 00000000 00:2a 416198                     /i915 (deleted)
7f65406b9000-7f65406ba000 r--p 00000000 08:05 435484                     /usr/share/locale/en_GB/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo
7f65406ba000-7f65406bb000 r--s 0001e000 08:06 6293017                    /home/name/builds/greenfoot/lib/bluej.jar
7f65406bb000-7f65406cd000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f65406cd000-7f65406d5000 rw-s 00000000 00:28 414358                     /tmp/hsperfdata_name/11568
7f65406d5000-7f65406d6000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f65406d6000-7f65406d7000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f65406d7000-7f65406d8000 r--p 00024000 08:05 394009                     /usr/lib/ld-2.26.so
7f65406d8000-7f65406d9000 rw-p 00025000 08:05 394009                     /usr/lib/ld-2.26.so
7f65406d9000-7f65406da000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ffda1b36000-7ffda1b57000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7ffda1b96000-7ffda1b99000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0                          [vvar]
7ffda1b99000-7ffda1b9b000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]

VM Arguments:
java_command: bluej.Boot -greenfoot=true -bluej.compiler.showunchecked=false
java_class_path (initial): /home/name/builds/greenfoot/lib/bluej.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk/lib/tools.jar
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/default/bin:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl:/home/name/.gem/ruby/2.4.0/bin
SHELL=/bin/zsh
DISPLAY=:0


---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS:NAME="Arch Linux"
PRETTY_NAME="Arch Linux"
ID=arch
ID_LIKE=archlinux
ANSI_COLOR="0;36"
HOME_URL="https://www.archlinux.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://bbs.archlinux.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.archlinux.org/"

uname:Linux 4.15.5-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Thu Feb 22 22:15:20 UTC 2018 x86_64
libc:glibc 2.26 NPTL 2.26 
rlimit: STACK 8192k, CORE infinity, NPROC 14476, NOFILE 4096, AS infinity
load average:10.10 3.57 2.31

/proc/meminfo:
...


CPU:total 4 (initial active 4) (2 cores per cpu, 2 threads per core) family 6 model 58 stepping 9, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, popcnt, avx, aes, clmul, erms, ht, tsc, tscinvbit, tscinv

...

Memory: 4k page, physical 3717376k(411948k free), swap 2097148k(1514492k free)

vm_info: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.162-b12) for linux-amd64 JRE (1.8.0_162-b12), built on Feb 27 2018 12:14:51 by "builduser" with gcc 7.3.0
```

Comment: What is the contents of `hs_err_pid11568.log`?

Comment: Hello. I attached the error log to the qeustion

Comment: This attached log is not full, it misses important parts.

Comment: I am sorry to ask but i have to ask, which part of the log do you need exactly? The thread.process or system section or information about the heap?

Comment: I think there is a bug in latest openjdk. I had a similar problem when using `sbt`. Downgrading java to previous version fixed it for me.
`cd /var/cache/pacman/pkg && sudo pacman -U jdk8-openjdk-8.u144-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz jre8-openjdk-8.u144-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz jre8-openjdk-headless-8.u144-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz`

Answer (score 0):

We have had issues with OpenJDK in the past where it has bugs that the official Oracle JDK did not, so our usual recommendation is to try Oracle JDK to see if that helps.  For this kind of query generally, it's best to contact our technical support via https://www.greenfoot.org/support.  If you email the address given there and attach the log we may be able to offer another suggestion, but as I said, I'd try the Oracle JDK if you can.